# Segregating tweets by dates gives warning

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am able to run a code, but there is a big paragraph of warning that comes below the cell in jupyter notebook. I am not able to make much sense out of it except the fact it creates a big distraction to my code. All I need a bit of tweaking help on my code so that whatever slight error it indicates can be weaned away. 
Please do not give me altogether new code because I am not a coding professional.
My code is as follows:

```
#segregating tweets2 based on dates.
tweets2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets2['created_at'], errors='coerce')
tweets2['date2'] = tweets2.date.dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')
```

And, the warning I get is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

I do not understand this a bit.
thanks!

Comment: That code isn't really problematic. The issue is probably few lines above that code, where you slice the `DataFrame` to create tweets2. Do you have chained assignment somewhere `][` or do you use a Boolean mask `m` like `df[m]` instead of `df.loc[m]`?

Comment: I created this dataframe `tweet2` by dropping the duplicates based on tweet id as follows:  `tweets2 = tweets.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep="first")`

Comment: Yes, that will do it. add `.copy()` onto the end `tweets2 = tweets.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep="first").copy()`. It seems `drop_duplicates`returns a view, though it's not stated in the docs, perhaps someone will provide an answer with more detail.

Comment: got it thanks that helped me.