# updating column value as loop over dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take links and push them via TinyURL.. I have a dataframe containing Login Links column and I would like to take those individually and add to column 'Tiny URL', the `tiny_urlize` link.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'Tiny Url'] = tiny_urlize(row['Login Link'])
```

The error I am getting looks like this:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

but this is exactly what I am doing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `df` itself a copy (e.g. did you do at some point before `df = other_df[some_slice]` ?

Comment: No, I never did that

Comment: Can you show how you define your `df`?

Comment: It can also be the result of a few methods that you wouldn't necessarily expect to return a copy. For instance [`df = df.drop_duplicates()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452965/segregating-tweets-by-dates-gives-warning#comment95714279_54452965) could be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

This error can pop up for a number of different reasons, a common case for example is that df is a slice of another dataframe. I suspect if you write `df = df.copy()` before your iterrows you won't get the error.

You can also simplify and speed up your expression by writing it as an `apply`:

```
df['Tiny Url'] = df['Login Link'].apply(tiny_urlize)
```

which I believe will also prevent the warning

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are updating the value of df using loc while looping (which is essentially a slice). Try,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Tiny Url'] = tiny_urlize(row['Login Link'])
```

Moreover, pandas has in-built functions which are very efficient for such things, one of them being `apply`.

```
df['Tiny Url'] = df['Login Link'].apply(tiny_urlize)
```